# Stringbuilder cannot append white space?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class ReverseWords {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        String str = "This is String , split by StringTokenizer, created by mkyong";
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str);
                char space =' ';
        System.out.println("---- Split by space ------");
        while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
            //System.out.println(st.nextElement());
                     output.insert(0,st.nextElement());
                     output.append(" ");
        }

        System.out.println(output.toString());
        /*System.out.println("---- Split by comma ',' ------");
        StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(str, ",");

        while (st2.hasMoreElements()) {
            System.out.println(st2.nextElement());
        }*/
    }
}
```

I'm trying to just reverse the words of a string and here is what I get:

```
mkyongbycreatedStringTokenizer,bysplit,StringisThis
```

Answer (score 7):

You are inserting the parts at the front, but all the space at the end.

You could do something like this to address this:

```
String s = st.nextElement();
output.insert(0, s);
output.insert(s.length(), " ");
```

Note that this is quite inefficient, as all the accumulated content is shifted back all the time.

Do you need to use a string tokenizer? Otherwise, you could just write

```
String[] parts = str.split(" ");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = parts.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  sb.append(parts[i]);
  sb.append(' ');
}
```

Comment: Or use the cleaner method of pushing all the tokens onto a stack and then popping them off into the output string.

Comment: `output.insert(0, " "); output.insert(0, st.nextElement());` would also work. But I don't know which one is "cleaner".

Comment: String s = st.nextElement();output.insert(0, " "); output.insert(0, st.nextElement()); Doesnt work. That leaves me with split .

Comment: @Raj you're calling st.nextElement() twice. That will skip some parts. Use output.insert(0, s) instead

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: Change this:

```
output.insert(0,st.nextElement());
output.append(" ");
```

to this:

```
output.insert(0,st.nextElement() + " ");
```

This makes the space character part of the string you're inserting at the front; the original code appended the space at the end, causing it to become separated from the string that `nextElement()` returned.